# Does YouTube API allow basic authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, youtube-api, basic-authentication

I am working on a [NodeJS module](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/youtube-api) which provides an object oriented wrapper for the YouTube v3 API.
In present it supports only OAuth 2.0 authentication protocol.

On [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) we find this:

> The **YouTube Data API supports the OAuth 2.0 protocol** for authorizing access to private user data.

Does this mean that YouTube REST API doesn't support basic authentication?
Is there any reference that proves that basic authentication cannot be implemented?

Is basic authentication supported/allowed?

Comment: For v3 of the API, oAuth2 is the sole supported method of authentication/authorization. Your module looks quite useful; is it possible to have it leverage already-existing oAuth clients for nodeJS? If you hook into something like Passport, you can get the tokens back and have your client then set them in the request headers, so it can then perform all the restricted actions.

Comment: I know how to get the access token, but I'm asking about basic auth via email+password.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is not supported in v3 of the API, to avoid the security problems inherent in presenting credentials to a 3rd party client (which the old ClientLogin scheme in v2 of the API was susceptible to).

Comment: @jlmcdonald Where is this mentioned?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Can this be helpful? https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin#ClientLogin_Authentication

Comment: @verdesrobert Yes, it is! The only bad side is that that API is deprecated. I tested and it works. You can add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this type of Authentication witch is pretty basic:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin#ClientLogin_Authentication

Here you have a sample Request:

```
POST /accounts/ClientLogin HTTP/1.0
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=jondoe@gmail.com&Passwd=north23AZ&service=cl&
   source=Gulp-CalGulp-1.05
```

Note that this type of authentication has been deprecated.

> **Note:** The YouTube Data API (v2) **has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014**. Please refer to our deprecation policy for more information.
>
> ---
>
> Important: **The ClientLogin authentication protocol has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012**. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 authentication as soon as possible. If you are building a new application, you should use OAuth 2.0 authentication.
>
> If you are already using ClientLogin and are encountering authentication failures with certain accounts, refer to the ClientLogin #FAIL blog post for recommendations.